# Android..error while finding address given location

Tags: android

I am an android beginner getting the error: cannot resolve the symbol isPresent, in my following code snippet. Experts, please help!

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(l.getLatitude(),l.getLongitude(),1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() >0){
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String addressText = String.format("%s,%s,%s", address.getLocality(),address.getCountryName());
                TextView place =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.place);
                place.setText(addressText);
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can you please try geo.isPresent()?

Comment: check whether you have given permission for location

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
  //code here
 }
```

replace it with

```
  if(geo.isPresent()){
   //code here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Lokesh..but that replacement is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well,the problem stands resolved. The error occurred because the snippet was appearing after a set of code, which were outside of the onCreate method.Sorry for the waste of time caused by this beginner.